# MongoError: not authorized on to execute command { find: "app_updates", filter: { key: "0.0.1-admins" }, limit: 1, batchSize: 1, singleBatch: true }

Tags: mongodb, opensuse, keystonejs

I start a KeystoneJS project following [this method](http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/). But after entering the project root directory and running `node keystone.js` I receive the error:

```
------------------------------------------------
An error occurred applying updates, bailing on Keystone init.

Error details:
MongoError: not authorized on <KeystoneJS project name> to execute command { find: "app_updates", filter: { key: "0.0.1-admins" }, limit: 1, batchSize: 1, singleBatch: true }
```

I researched on this error but I couldn't resolve it. I'm on OpenSUSE, and was working with `nodejs8` package.

---

When I start the mongodb on systemd by running:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mongodb.service
```

... I receive  the above error.

---

But when I start the mongodb by running:

```
$ sudo mongod
```

... I don't receive any error and keystonejs works fine, I'm not sure why!

---

When I start mongodb by running `$ sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf` I receive the above error. But When I start mongodb by running `$ sudo mongod`, I don't receive any error. Therefore, looks like the problem cause is within the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file which is as follows:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  #dbPath: /data/db/
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# Where and how to log messages.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logRotate: reopen

# What type of connections to allow.
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  ipv6: true
  http:
    enabled: false
    JSONPEnabled: false
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: false


# How to manage mongod.
processManagement:
  fork: true

# Security settings.
security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your config you're using authorization for accessing Mongo

```
# Security settings.
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

At first you need to create user - open mongo console (mongo)
Start mongod without config

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
```

connect to the instance using console

```
mongo --port 27017
```

in mongo console enter next commands

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "superAdmin",
    pwd: "admin123",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  })
```

Now you can access mongo using as a service with your config

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "superAdmin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

So you need to grant access to mongo by creating new user with ReadWrite permission

```
use myAppDb #its name of your Database
db.createUser(
  {
   user: "myAppDbUser", #desired username
   pwd: "myApp123", #desired password
   roles: [ "readWrite"]
  })
```

And try to connect using this credentials
    mongo --port 27017 -u "myAppDbUser" -p "myApp123" --authenticationDatabase "myAppDb"

and use this user for keystone config to connect to mongo, for example

```
mongodb://myAppDbUser:myApp123@localhost:27017/myAppDb
```

(via https://medium.com/@raj_adroit/mongodb-enable-authentication-enable-access-control-e8a75a26d332)

Comment: From version 4.2 you can or even should use function `passwordPrompt()` i.e. something like this: `db.createUser({user:"superuser", pwd:passwordPrompt(), roles:["root"]})`. This is considered more secure than typing password that is visible on the screen. Be careful, password prompt is displayed only once. It does NOT ask you to retype your password. If you go with `use admin` then `db: "admin"` is not required.

Comment: the first user i created, i mess up with the role! and add readWrite instead of root! is there anyway to role back? or factory reset my mongo instance? or modify the user?

Comment: @Fraga Turn off authorization in the config file and run the Mongo shell from the localhost. You can then do anything including creating new users and modifying permissions of your existing user.