# MongoDB not authorized error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing a server on Digitalocean and have a MongoDB issue. I installed Mongo on the server and allowed remote access.

I created two users. One is super-user for me and the other is a regular user for the website users. **I am able to connect to the mongo through Robomongo 3T (a mongo client) remotely for both users**.

However, when I use the application from a browser, a simple login request gives an authentication error. Here is the error:

```
MongoError: not authorized on DATABASE_NAME to execute command { find: "users", filter: { email: "YYY", password: "XXX" }, limit: 1,           singleBatch: true, batchSize: 1 }
```

Here is the realted server-side code:

Connecting the database at server.js:

```
MongoClient.connect(config.mongo_url, (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('db connected')
    app.locals.db = client
    // start the server
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()=>console.log('listening on port 3000!'))
});
```

Trying to connect to the local mongo on the server:

```
database.collection(config.mongo_col_user)
.findOne({
    email: username,
    password: hash
}, (err, user)=>{
    if(err) return done(err)
    if(!user) return done(null, false, {msg: 'not found'})
    if(user.password)
    return done(null, user)
})
```

I use pm2 on the server side and I use `ecosystem.config.js` which has the below code:

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [
        {
          name: "NAME",
          script: "SCRIPT_NAME",
          watch: true,
          env: {
            "mongo_url": 'mongodb://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=DATABASE_NAME',
            "mongo_db_name": 'DATABASE_NAME',
            "mongo_col_query": "COLLECTION_NAME",
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you help with the problem please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoError: not authorized on to execute command { find: "app\_updates", filter: { key: "0.0.1-admins" }, limit: 1, batchSize: 1, singleBatch: true }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130379/mongoerror-not-authorized-on-to-execute-command-find-app-updates-filter)

Comment: I believe it is not. Actually I did all the things that the answer suggested. My problem is that it gives me an error when it tries to connect it from the REST API although I can connect from shell and Robomongo.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

When I did make changes to pm2 environment file ecosystem.config.js, I did always restart pm2 with `pm2 restart all`. However, when you change the file, you should tell pm2 that you changed it by `pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --update-env`.

Additionally, the correct syntax is no

`mongodb://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=DATABASE_NAME'`

but

`mongodb://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/DATABASE_NAME'`